# substitution and colouring paragraph

Tags: python

I'm trying to combine the following code to make one python project. The first one makes capital letters red and the second substitutes letters in a paragraph. Could someone please show/tell me how to combine them to make the variable text work with substitutions and colouring capital letters?

1.

```
from termcolor import colored

word = "VEP HYXHLVHTP MO AWFJYFLT H RFNEPS HJNEHAPV FL VEFU"
color = "red"

colored_str = ""
for letter in word:
    if not letter.islower():
        colored_str += colored(letter, color)
    else:
        colored_str += letter
print(colored_str)
```

2. 

```
text = 'VEP HYXHLVHTP MO AWFJYFLT H RFNEPS HJNEHAPV FL VEFU' 

replaced_text = text.replace('V', 't')
print(replaced_text)
```

Comment: What about making functions to encapsulate the logic of 1?  Something like `new_text = color_text(text.repalce('V', 't'), 'red')`

Comment: just switch letter to letter.replace('V', 't') in your if part in 1st snippet.

Comment: or word = "VEP HYXHLVHTP MO AWFJYFLT H RFNEPS HJNEHAPV FL VEFU".replace('V', 't')